# Deleting /wp from my website URL

Tags: domain, site-url, hosting, ftp

I'm newby in creating websites and I have the following case...

My website was working only on url Makai.pl/wp if i would enter Makai.pl there would be my hosting site. I'v tried to move all the content of wp folder in FTP out of the folder as I'v read somewhere on the forum to make my site working on my domain. It totally didnt work so i placed the content again in the wp folder in my FTP and now when I go to my Makai.pl it redirects me to Makai.pl/wp.

Could You guys help me moving it to the correct url without the /wp ending?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should review the official documentation on moving WordPress: https://wordpress.org/support/article/moving-wordpress/#moving-directories-on-your-existing-server

Comment: and if you're still having problems you'll need to give us more details about exactly what you've done, what doesn't work and what you see.

Answer (score 0):

You used subdirectory /wp to install your wordpress installation. To change the installation location you would need to export your database , search and replace all text string  "http:s//Makai.pl/wp" replace with "https://Makai.pl", afterwards , move all files in /wp directory one level up , which should be /public_html or /www directory. After those steps are complete navigate in admin dashboard to "settings->permalinks and press save. Hope that helps.